# The joined path (relative path) is located outside of the base path component (full path)

Tags: django, django-templates, sorl-thumbnail

I am trying to use thumbnail packages to generate thumbnail images from base images. Originally, I had my source images in my static dir, and as the thumbnail packages want to generate them to my media dir, I thought that was the cause of the SuspiciousFileOperation error I was getting.

No problem, I just copied my images to my media dir, which I thought would solve the issue, but no, the issue remains.

From what I can tell, it seems to be a problem with having a relative path vs a full path?

The full error is:

```
SuspiciousFileOperation at /toys/
The joined path (/media/images/test.jpg) is located outside of the base path component (/home/username/django/first_webapp/my_site/media)
```

The path /home/username/django/first_webapp/my_site/media/images/test.jpg is valid and test.jpg is a valid jpg image.

The abridged code I am using in my template, with sorl-thumbnail (although I have also tried with easy_thumbnails) is:

```
{% for instance in prods %}
    <img src=" {% thumbnail instance.image_url 300x300 %} "> 
{% endfor %}
```

instance.image_url, in this case, is set to `/media/images/test.jpg`

My media directory settings from my settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I am unsure where to begin to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Post the models code which has `image_url` field.

Comment: @ans2human I don't see how that is relevant? If I remove `thumbnail` and `300x300` from my img src declaration, the image displays fine without issue. I don't see how it could be a problem with my models.

Comment: i just wished to see if your image field name was `image_url` and what field type you've used, that can be `Filefield`, `ImageField`, `URLField`. Therefore, i thought it to be relevant.

Comment: @ans2human OK, I was just curious. I have image_url set as TextField, like so: `image_url = models.TextField(null='true')` -- I can't see this being a problem as the thumbnail packages just needs a URl string to be passed.

Comment: What *exactly* is the content of this field? And why are you using a text field target than an image field?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, as per my question text, the context of the field is exactly `/media/images/test.jpg`. I am using a textfield because I saw no need to use an image field. The field contains a relative path URL, which works fine when passed as a src parameter to the img tag in a template. 

Given the error I am getting, which indicates the URL is being extracted and processed, I don't see how using a text field vs an image field is relevant to this particular problem. If it is, could you explain how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really understand how you think the type of the field is not relevant. Of course it is.

In your case, you have (for some reason) used a TextField to store the path of your image file. TextFields have no special knowledge of media files, and sort-thumbnail just treats the contents as a path component, which it then joins with MEDIA_ROOT. But since your path begins with a leading slash, the result of `os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, path)` is just `path`; the leading slash means exactly "start from the filesystem root". So the result is a path outside your project, which Django disallows for security reasons.

A quick fix is to remove the leading slash - as well as the duplicate "media" prefix - and just store "images/test.jpg". But the real fix is to use the appropriate field for the content you are storing, and let that field manage it for you.

Comment: I can't really understand why you think an image_field needs to be used here. The variable in question only contains a relative path to a URL, nothing else. I am using django to load data that was manually inserted into a postgres database. How would using an image_field really make a difference here? I'm not trying to be snarky, I would like to genuinely understand.

Sorl-thumbnail treating the contents as a parth component is as far as I can see, expected behaviour. When using sorl-thumbnail in a template, it expects a URL as a parameter.

Comment: If I can pass it a URL manually, why would passing it via a textfield cause a problem? I'm going to try playing around with paths, and will quickly accept your answer if that is the solution, thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The parameter to `thumbnail` is a *file path*, whereas using the literal string in an img src uses it as a URL. The two are unrelated.

Comment: Maybe that has been the cause of my issue. I was seeing the file path and the url as  the same thing. I understand they are different, but practically, they are the same text used in a different way. The file path is not a full path but a relative path, which can double as the url when appended to my base web address.

If I have my variable as containing /media/blah/blah.jpg, that works as a file path because django knows  it is relative to my media dir, and it works as a url because it can be appended to my base web address and load the image.

Comment: OK, So, I have it working, kind of! By changing my image_url field to have a full file path, it works and the thumbnails are generated. Of course, I can no longer pass this as a url to img src to display. So, I am thinking of adding an extra field to my model to contain the full file path, so I can pass image_path to sorl-thumbnail and image_url to img src (to display the full resolution image).

Comment: While I am using django models, the data is being inserted into the database manually, as I am pulling it from an external API, and there are thousands of rows. This approach has worked well for me even if it is not the preferred way. Adding the additional field with full file path seems like it will fix my issue. Given that I am inserting the data manually, how would using an image_field make a difference in this case?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who lands here off Google because upgrading their Django and easy-thumbnails caused the same error to start happening, check that your template is referencing your `ImageField` as `{{image_field|thumbnail_url:'default'}}`, not `{{image_field.url|thumbnail_url:'default'}}`.

Apparently it got less forgiving of that mistake.